# Iterating over rows of 2-dimensional array containing arrays of different length

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ramda.js

I have a function that picks all elements from a 2-dimensional array by its rows and returns a 1-dimensional array.
The array has a variable amount of columns and rows.

Example:

```
let arr = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
];
```

Returns:

```
[1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10, 3, 7, 11, 4, 8, 12]
```

The function i came up with:

```
convertList = (list) => {
    let result = [];
    let listTotalEntries = R.sum(R.map(R.length)(list));
    let mod = R.modulo(R.__, list.length);

        let counterRow = -1;

        for (let i = 0; i < listTotalEntries; i++) {
            if (mod(i) === 0) {
                counterRow++;
            }
            if (list[mod(i)][counterRow]) {
                result.push(list[mod(i)][counterRow]);
                console.log(list[mod(i)][counterRow]);
            }
        }
        console.log(result);
        return result;
};
```

**Question:** This function works only with square matrices - how can i make it work with a variable length of the contained arrays?

Example:

```
let arr = [
    [1, 2],
    [],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
];
```

Should return:

```
[1, 9, 2, 10, 11, 12]
```

Thanks for your help!

Muff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a `ramda.js` tag in here.  With Ramda, it's pretty simple, since there are two functions that will help:

```
const convertList = compose(flatten, transpose);
convertList(arr); //=> [1, 9, 2, 10, 11, 12]
```

[`transpose`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#transpose) flips a matrix over its main diagonal, that is, changing rows to columns and vice versa.  [`flatten`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten) turns a list of lists into a plain list.  So [`compose`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose)ing like this essentially creates the equivalent of `list => flatten(transpose(list))`.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://goo.gl/j3spfu)**.

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm, lean and neat! I didn't realise a function like transpose exists in Ramda - It takes some time and experience to internalize all the functions and associated possibilities. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the Ramda team is working on improving ways to discover functions.  One step in that was [just published yesterday](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/What-Function-Should-I-Use%3F).

Comment: Great! *Bookmarked*  - I'm looking forward to the progression of the manual/ guide. I've found one for Version 0.17 but it seemed there were only introductory chapters available yet. I hope they continue writing on it as a proper complement to the docs.

Comment: That's been stalled, but we're hoping to get back to it sometime soon.  BTW, although it's listed under the specific version, it's really fairly generic.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this simple one?

```
var singleDimensionArr = arr.reduce(function(prev,current){return prev.concat(current)});
```

For example

```
[
    [1, 2],
    [],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
].reduce(function(prev,current){return prev.concat(current)});
```

outputs `[1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 12]`

**Edit:**

Based on the inputs from OP below, since the concatenation needs to happen column wise

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr.map(function (a) { return a.length; }));
var finalArr = []; for( var i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
   for( var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
   {
       arr[j][i] ? finalArr.push(arr[j][i]) : "";
   }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: That doesn't match the result that the OP added

Comment: Sorry i had a typo in the return statement, 9 and 2 where flipped i corrected it.
Your solution picks out the items by columns - i would like to pick the items by row.

Comment: @Marie because there was a typo (which totally changed the question).

Comment: now you basically the same as my answer, but you do not return falsey values, eg `0`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, I couldn't top how you evaluated `max`. If you want you can downvote me for that :)

Comment: comment is enough.

Comment: @gurvinder When i run your solution i get the original array in return.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to go step-by-step through the arrays

```js
var arr1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]],
    arr2 = [[1, 2], [], [9, 10, 11, 12]];

function single(array) {
    var r = [],
        max = Math.max.apply(null, array.map(function (a) { return a.length; })),
        i = 0, j,
        l = array.length;

    while (i < max) {
        for (j = 0; j < l ; j++) {
            i in array[j] && r.push(array[j][i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return r;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(single(arr1), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(single(arr2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks - I upvoted your solution and checked James' since it's a little more compact and uses reduce and filter.

Comment: @Raggamuffin, it may looks more compact, but it does not necessarily perform better than a while loop and a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This example makes a big sparse array putting each item where it would belong if the array were square.  Then it filters out null values which occur where no input item was present.

```js
let arr = [
    [1, 2],
    [],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
];

var out = arr.reduce(function(o,n,i,a) {
  for (var j=0;j<n.length;j++){
    o[a.length * j + i] = n[j];
  }
  return o;
},[]).filter(function(n) {
  return n !== null;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(out));
```